# how to eliminate erratic mktime behavior

Tags: mktime

I'm trying to convert a local time into the number of seconds since the Epoch.  However, it doesn't seem like mktime() always returns the same value for the same input.

Here is the code:

```
int TimeCreated;
// ...
printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d\n",t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min,t.tm_c);
TimeCreated = mktime(&t);
printf("%d\n",TimeCreated);
printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d\n",t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min,t.tm_c);
TimeCreated = mktime(&t);
printf("%d\n",TimeCreated);
```

It seems like every time I run the problem, the output of mktime() changes for the same input value:

```
$ ./test1
115/2/28 15:29:1
1427581741
115/2/28 15:29:1
1427581741
$ test1
115/2/28 15:29:1
1427578141
115/2/28 14:29:1
1427578141
```

The man page says "The functions mktime() and timegm() convert the broken-out time (in the structure pointed to by *timeptr) into a time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by the time(3) function (that is, seconds from the Epoch, UTC).  The mktime() function interprets the input structure according to the current timezone setting (see tzset(3))" which suggests the problem is time zone related.  However, the time zone is set correctly.

If I extract just the above code from the larger program it is part of, the problem goes away. I suspect linking against and calling functions in `jhead` may be part of the problem, but I can't imagine from reading the map page how it could be perturbing mktime() results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `tm_isdst` field of the `struct tm` is not initialized before the first call to `mktime()`. *The value is positive if daylight saving time is in effect, zero if it is not, and negative if the information is not available.*

Comment: that's it, thanks!  the smaller test program apparently was in a different place on the stack that was zero.